# Type hinting for an identity function

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I want to type a defection for a function which returns its passed argument, the argument could be of any type, the important thing ***is to reflect the interface of the argument to the return value***.

For example on line 6 in the image below, I want to type `z.` and then immediately I want the code editor to show me auto-completion, so it should show the option **a**.

[image]

How to define this in JSDoc?

Since typescript inference can't detect this, and I'm using VS Code, and since I'm using vanilla JavaScript so how to make it in **JsDoc**?

```js
function returnMe(x) {
  return x
}

const z = returnMe({a:2})
z. //  here I want to get auto completion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do it? From https://medium.com/@antonkrinitsyn/jsdoc-generic-types-typescript-db213cf48640.

```
/**
 * @template A
 * @param {A} val
 * @returns {A}
 */
function ident(val) {
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Genau! yes it does

Answer (score 0):

Found it, surprisingly, while reading on Wikipedia, this is called an **identity function** in programming, it's a function which returns its arguments.

Simply, define a `@template` + `@param` + `@returns` as follows:

```
/** 
  @template IdentityA
  @param {IdentityA} x
  @returns {IdentityA}
*/
function returnMe(x) {
  return x
}

const z = returnMe({
  a: 2
})
z. //  Now you'll get warnings about the types and you'll get auto completion!
```